# How can I make a program run with admin rights while retaining a limited user's context? (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, backup, administrator, limited-user-account

My company has a policy that whoever has admin rights has two user accounts: one limited account for everyday use, and one special account with administrative rights but other restrictions (lack of access to certain accounts). The problem is that I need to do something that requires both admin rights and the limited account's abilities.

To be more precise, I have a drive that I use for system backups. As is standard for security reasons, you can only access that folder with admin rights. However, I'm trying to copy that data to a different location which requires the permissions that the limited account has (access to certain networks).

I am trying to accomplish this with a scheduled task which appears when it's being run (so that it can be paused in case I need to remove the external disk). Mind you, that's not too relevant for this question - once I know how to run something with admin rights in the limited user's context, than I can figure out the rest.

What I've considered/tried:

- Storing the data in a separate location. This won't work because of storage constraints
- temporarily granting the limited user admin privileges while launching the task. This worked in Windows 7, but doesn't work anymore in Windows 10.
- Granting the limited user permission to access the data. I would not want to do this, because then the backup data can be accessed without admin permission, which I want to avoid for security reasons (thinking of ransomware).
- creating a scheduled task with the admin account, selecting execute with highest privileges, and running as the limited user account. Seemed to easy... Turned out it was.

Any ideas? Have I missed anything? Or is this just wholly impossible?

Comment: A privilege user by default runs with the lowest amount of privileges they are allowed access to.  If your Administrator user is not granted rights or is not a member of the same user groups, then there is no way to do what you want, without giving a single user access to that.  In your case the schedule task would run as a non-elevated process, unless you specifically escalated the permissions on the task, which can be done but shouldn't really be used.  The best you can do with a normal user is run a script with "run as administrator"

Comment: Just because a user is an Administrator, unless they have been explicitly granted permissions to a file or folder, does not mean they actually have access.  You can indeed configure a folder so it's only accessible to non-privileged users, of course as an Administrator, you can overwrite that configuration at any point.

Comment: You can't use a temporary folder for copying the file to it as admin, then copying from it via the standard user?

Comment: @Ramhound What do you mean with escalating permissions on the task? What are the reasons it shouldn't be done?

Comment: @harrymc It would be fairly difficult, since it's a fairly large amount of data. I would have to find a place where I can dump all of that data in the mean time, which is something I don't really have. And ideally at some point (although a separate point), I would like to turn it into more of a "sync" operation rather than a "move" operation.

Comment: Can you create a new admin account with the right permissions on the networks? Maybe a scheduled task running as NETWORK SERVICE be able to access everything.

Comment: @harrymc sorry for the late response. I've now tried that, and NETWORK SERVICE doesn't seem to have access. Only the User as such has access. Thanks though, it was worth a try...

Comment: The only solution then is to create a new account that is both an admin and has rights on the share. You have shot down all other solutions.

Comment: @harrymc OK, I guess that's just the way it is, then. Thanks anyway for the help!